# How to decrypt a string in php a string encrypted in nodejs

Tags: php, node.js

Goodmorning,
I am trying to implement some new things on a legacy system.
To manage the authentication I need to pass an encrypted string that comes from a nodejs source to a php page and decrypt it and verify it.

The following code is what I have tried to do, the main problem is that I cannot change the nodejs code, even if it is deprecated, so I have to try to implement the correct way to decrypt it in php, the password is the same, the algorithm is `aes-256-ctr` and there is no padding and initialization vector.

NODE.JS CODE

```
function encrypt(text) {
  var cipher = crypto.createCipher(algorithm, password())
  cipher.setAutoPadding(false);
  var crypted = cipher.update(text, 'utf8', 'hex')
  crypted += cipher.final('hex')
  return crypted
}
function decrypt(text) {
  var decipher = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm, password())
  decipher.setAutoPadding(false);
  var dec = decipher.update(text, 'hex', 'utf8')
  dec += decipher.final('utf8')
  return dec
}
```

PHP CODE

```
function decrypt($text)
{
    return openssl_decrypt(hex2bin($text), _algorithm_, password(), OPENSSL_NO_PADDING);
}
```

Somehow these two decrypt works in a different way, what can I do to make the php one behave as the nodejs decrypt?

EDIT: as suggested by @Chris Haas I checked if the conversion by and from hex or utf-8 are the same, and I can confirm that they are the same

```
var Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer
const buf = Buffer.from('hello world', 'utf8');
console.log(buf.toString('hex'));

echo bin2hex("hello world");
```

Comment: Can you try `$decrypted = openssl_decrypt(hex2bin($text), algorithm, password(), OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, "");`

Comment: The output is the same, either with an empty string or without the argument

Comment: Before you get too far with decryption, first make sure that `hex2bin` in PHP produces 100% identical content when compared to JS.

Comment: To be honest I do not really know how to test since I cannot find the source code of the crypto library of nodejs, and the documentation does not tell how it is converted